# Problem with Apache2 Reverse Proxy for docker containers

Tags: docker, apache2, reverse-proxy

I try to setup apache2 as reverse proxy for docker container app([FileBrowser](https://filebrowser.org/) or [Filestash](https://www.filestash.app/)).
The thing is that the normal `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` don't work (probably some websocket thing as far as i figured out) cause they just stuck on loading screen.

Apps work normally on local network with http://ip:port/ i want to expose it to internet with apache. And it must be subdirectory of my main domain like: `https://my.domain/app`

I found the proxy setup for nginx for one of the apps but i can't translate it to apache2 properly:

```
client_max_body_size 1024M;

location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade \$http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    proxy_set_header     Host \$host:\$server_port;
    proxy_set_header     X-Real-IP \$remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-Proto \$scheme;
    proxy_set_header     Origin '';

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

    proxy_pass           http://127.0.0.1:8334;
    proxy_read_timeout   86400;
}
```

Somebody can help me please?

Update: i also tried following config (with or without rewrite):

```
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
        RewriteRule /(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P,L]

        <Location /filebrowser>
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/
            ProxyPassReverse /filebrowser
        </Location>
```

It doesn't work